# C# WinForms. Check if text matches C syntax (maybe regex?)

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a flowchart editor, elements of flowchart are stored in a List.
For example, I built this flowchart:

[image: FlowChart Example]

> Blocks 2-6 stored in Block1.left List.
>
> Block7 stored in Block5.left List.
>
> Block8 stored in Block5.right List.

Then I wrote the code in a RichTextBox that I think will fit the flowchart. Now I need to check if my code in the RichTextBox is correct.

If there are errors in the code I need to highlight the first error in the text, output some info about the error and highlight the block in the flowchart.

I am thinking about doing this with Regex but this might not be the right way.

I have a string field `code` in Block class.
For example, `BEGIN.code="(^void\s*)(([A-Za-z]+)[0-9]*)(\((void|)\))"`.
So I do

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text,code))
{
    index += Regex.Match(text, code).Length;
}
```

and then check `text.substring(index,text.length - index)` with `BEGIN.left[0].code`.

I think that I need regular expressions only for `Begin`, `Input` and `Output` blocks.
Maybe something like this:

```
BEGIN.code="(^void\s*)(([A-Za-z]+)[0-9]*)(\((void|)\))"
INPUT.code="(^scanf\\(\")(( *%[A-Za-z0-9.?]+) *)\"((, *(&|)[A-Za-z]+)*)\\)"
```

What should I do if there are no matches? how can I find the position of the error?
Or should I try to do it in another way, not with Regex?

Comment: I suppose that in your "code" field you want to keep C# code which will be compiled dynamically via CSharpCodeProvider?

Comment: @MaciejŚwierczek looks more like C to me (`scanf`, `printf` and the title says `C`)

Comment: No, I use "code" only for comparing it with text in richTextBox. @MaciejŚwierczek

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer Sorry - my bad. :)